# How do I change the sprite in the timer when the object is created but is not visible camera?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to change its sprite after a time if the object is not visible camera.
I have a method that creates an object

```
 private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, Drop.WIDTH - 100);
    raindrop.y = Drop.WIDTH;
    raindrop.width = 100;
    raindrop.height = 100;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

I have a method that changes the time interval through the sprites:
 public void timerSpriteChange() {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {


                               index = ((int) (Math.random() * MAX_SPRITES));



                       }
                   }

            , 0, 5);

}
```

here I check and compare the time and call the method

```
  if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) {

            spawnRaindrop();

        }
```

OrthographicCamera camera;

Comment: Does your camera move around? Or does it stay still and everything else moves?

Comment: Yes that's right, everything else moves
I create 
camera. 800 ,480

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of making up a boolean like 'raindropVisible' that when you create the object and spawn it, it sets the boolean true, when the game disposes of it, it sets it false. Then make the timer check if the boolean is false, and if it is, change the sprite?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done it, your Raindrop class should extend the libGDX `Actor` class and then use the methods `act` and `draw` to handle everything.

*This code is untested*

```
class Raindrop extends Actor
{
    boolean onScreen = true;
    float offScreenTimer = 0.0f;
    final float OFFSCREENLLIMIT = 10.0f; // change as required

    // here you will also define all the other variables you need
    // such as movement speed, position information, sprite/image, etc

    public void act()
    {
        if ( onScreen )
        {
          if ( isOnScreen() ) // you'll need to create this method yourself!
          {
              // do all your on screen 'acting' here (movement, etc), but not the drawing
          }
          else
          {
              onScreen = false;
              setVisible(false);
          }
        }
        else
        {
            offScreenTimer += Gdx.gl.getDelta(); // <= this is most likely wrong, you'll need to double check the method name
            if ( offScreenTimer > OFFSCREENLLIMIT )
            {
                // here add all the code you need to change the image
                // and reset its movement and position values
                setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        // add your code to handle the drawing of the image here
    }
}
```